# How do I associate torrent files with Vuze?

Tags: 14.04, bittorrent, torrent-client, vuze

- OS: 14.04
- Browser: Firefox

Firefox is only saving torrent files to hard drive. How do I associate .torrent files with Vuze so it opens the client automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on a torrent file and choose `Properties > Open With`.
Select Vuze from the list and press `Set as Default` button
[image]

Comment: and if vuze isn't listed?