# Vuze not listed as an application and so cannot associate with torrent files

Tags: firefox, bittorrent, transmission, torrent-client, vuze

How do I ensure that `vuze` is listed in the apps for firefox to [associate](https://askubuntu.com/q/589630/45156) torrent files with it?

[image: no vuze]

Transmission is [listed](https://askubuntu.com/q/384375/45156) and works fine with Firefox, for what that's worth.  Installed vuze with snap:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ snap find vuze
Name     Version        Developer  Notes  Summary
vuze-vs  5.7.6.0-snap1  vs         -      Vuze is a powerful, open source, bittorrent client.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
thufir@dur:~$
```

[image: new apps]

Perhaps it's a problem [between](https://askubuntu.com/q/1030689/45156) snap and apt.

Comment: 'Find new applications'.

Comment: @Rinzwind unfortunately, `vuze` isn't listed.

Comment: Ehm? Am I missing something? That option should open your file system where you find the vuze executable and then add it?